# What is the difference between `${var:-value}` and `${var:=value}`?

Tags: shell

I do not understand the difference between `${var:-value}` and `${var:=value}`.
It seems that both commands in shell work identically.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `var` is unset or null:

- `${var:-value}` will expand to "value"
- `${var:=value}` will expand to "value" **and set var=value**

Demo

```
$ var=

$ echo "${var:-y}"; echo ">$var<"
y
><

$ echo "${var:=y}"; echo ">$var<"
y
>y<
```

Doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

Both do *something* if the variable is unset or null (an empty value).

If you happen to be assigning the expression to something, or using it in a here-document, both may *appear* to be doing the same thing, since the unset/null `var` is replaced by `$value`.

But the difference is that the latter one **also** assigns `$value` to `var`, so that it can be used in subsequent shell expressions.

That is often used in this idiom:

```
: ${var:=value}
```

to assign the default value where none exists.